# How to enter multiple records at once in VBA (Microsoft Access)

Tags: sql, vba, excel, ms-access

I am trying to enter thousands of records into an Access Database from a .txt file. Currently I am looping through the records and adding them one at a time. Sometime this can take over 30 minutes. Is there a way to load the records into memory like an array and then execute it at the end of the routine and have all the records entered at once?

There is this thread, but I can't get DAO to work, when I try to select the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library in reference library, I get a .dll error. [VBA to insert many records into access DB fast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12930603/vba-to-insert-many-records-into-access-db-fast?rq=1)

Thanks

EDIT: If this is not possible in MS Access, can it be done with MySQL or another Database?

Comment: Using the Access data import tools is the absolute last option, I need it done via VBA.

Comment: [DoCmd.TransferText](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff835958.aspx) is a VBA method to import data from txt, csv, etc. files

Comment: What about when you have to split the text to enter into fields?

Comment: *but I can't get DAO to work, when I try to select the Microsoft DAO 3.6 Object Library in reference library, I get a .dll error.* - There is your problem. What Access version do you use, and what exact error do you get?

Comment: Excel is 2013 and so is Access. DAO is old stuff, is there not another way using ADODB. I can't give you the exact error, b/c it is in Japanese, but translates that there was an error when reading the DLL after clicking OK in the reference library. There is not error code/No. to refer to either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to the *Microsoft Office 15.0 Access database engine Object Library*. This is the current and default engine for Access. In Access, ADODB is only used in special cases.

Then you can either link the text file as a table and run an append query to copy the records to your table, or you can read the file line by line a call `AddNew ... Update` for each record. Or you can run `DoCmd.TransferText` as mentioned by @Parfait or use the import wizard.